# correct usage of "to the maximum" or "to its maximum"

Tags: determiners

I have a lot of trouble trying to figure the correct determiner for "maximum".

(1a) The attendance at the workshop reached **the** maximum.

(1b) The attendance at the workshop reached **its** maximum.

(2a) Enrollment for all the courses reached **the** maximum.

(2b) Enrollment for all the courses reached **its** maximum.

Which one is correct: the maximum or its maximum?

Answer (score 1):

All of your sentences are correct and natural except (2b), which is only wrong because "Enrollment for all the courses" should be treated as a plural subject because each course has its own enrollment, so it should read, "*... reached **their** maximum**s***".

Also consider these two versions with no determiner, which are at least as natural sounding:

> The attendance at the workshop reached maximum.
> Enrollment for all the courses reached maximum.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.